Parasite infecting pets and humans protected by the local law: which Star Trek episode that was?
I vaguely remember the episode, but I cannot find it. I believe it was TNG, with less probability it could be Enterprise or Voyager, I don't think it was DS9.
Enterprise(?) is orbiting a planet, one of the crew members (Riker?) takes a shore leave and brings back a local animal, and is going to keep it as a pet. The pet looks moderately weird, but the owner finds it very nice. (Well, it would be bad manners to tell someone "your taste is perverted", so the others just look at the owner strangely.)
Nevertheless, as time passes, more and more crew members find these pets attractive and acquire them.
Finally, the doctor (Crusher? or the other one, Pulaski?) finds out that these pets are all infected with a parasite, and the crew members also got infected. (This is why they found these pets attractive, by the way: they were infected.) Of course, the doctor eliminates the parasite.
Either the doctor or the captain informs the people of the planet below about the parasite (and probably offers help to heal everyone).
The reply from surface is shocking: they know about the parasite, and killing that parasite is a serious crime. They want to prosecute the doctor. (And the laws of the planet sort of should apply to the orbit as well, and the crew sort of must not violate the local laws.)
The captain orders Enterprise to leave the planet's system.
(I remember I wondered if they have screwed all diplomatic relations between that planet and the Federation.)
The prototype of that parasite was likely toxoplasmosis, but in fact there are many parasites on Earth that change behaviour of their hosts in a way beneficial to the parasite. The unusual thing is that protection of the parasite became a law on that planet.

Not any episode of ST (any series) AFAICT. Maybe a novel?

Wasn't an animated series was it?

@JiminyCricket. No, the pet was made of... whatever they make them in Hollywood. But it was not a drawing.

I'd be very surprised if this is a TNG, Voyager or DS9 episode (I missed some Voyager/Enterprise eps); it doesn't seem familiar at all.  Picard had the chance to let the parasitic life form known as Wesley be destroyed for his crimes, but that's another story

Do you have a sense of roughly when you watched this?

@LogicDictates between 2000 and 2010

The Orville comes to mind, but I don't see a matching episode.

This doesn't sound like any specific episode of Star Trek up through Enterprise, although your description does seem to contain bits and pieces of various episodes. There have been various episodes where people get exotic pets, become infected, find a cure, and are judged by planetary law, but none I can recall that contain all of that. Maybe it was a Farscape or Andromeda episode (I'm less familiar with them), as they aired around the same time (90s to early 00s).

There's Andromeda's For Whom The Bell Tolls, where Harper inadvertently brings a dangerous maggot aboard the ship (and is accused of bringing a pet onboard). Farscape, the crew adopts a Vork to chase down parasites that paralyzes and cause convulsions, Beware the Dog. The Vork is trouble, naturally.

After a thorough refresher journey through all plot synopses for all episodes of TOS, TNG, DS9, VOY, and ENT: the described events do not conform to any single episode of any of the aforementioned Star Trek series.
Various plot points match jumbled bits and bobs of various episodes, but no single episode contains all (or even most) of these plot points at once.
For example, "time passes, more and more crew members find these pets attractive and acquire them" is matched in a couple of ways across series:
Riker brings aboard a mind-controlling Ktarian game in "The Game" (TNG Season 5 episode 5) and spreads this through the crew. Spock is infected by alien spores which ultimately infect nearly the entire crew in TOS "This Side of Paradise." (TOS Season 2 episode 11) Although this matches the "(implied voluntarily) spreads through the crew" portion, they are not pets.
Similarly, Tribbles are kept as pets and spread like wildfire across the Enterprise and Deep Space Station K7 in the classic TOS episode "The Trouble With Tribbles" (TOS Season 2 episode 14), but the Tribbles do not harbor dangerous parasites and the doctor's involvement is centered around determining why Tribbles breed so quickly and the cause of death for various Tribbles on the space station.
The ship's doctor eliminates deadly parasites or some sort of (broadly speaking) infection in more episodes than I care to recount (brief sample: TOS: The Deadly Years, TOS: The Naked Time, TNG: The Naked Now, DS9: Armageddon Game, DS9: The Quickening, VOY: oh holy crap this was practically every week, ENT: Terra Nova, et al.)
"And the laws of the planet sort of should apply to the orbit as well, and the crew sort of must not violate the local laws" and "The captain orders Enterprise to leave the planet's system" is a plot point match for TNG Season 1 episode 8 "Justice", in which young Wesley Crusher commits a wildly trivial offense while on an alien planet and is sentenced to death, and Picard ultimately orders the Enterprise to leave and abandon the planet in order to save Wesley's life.
As mentioned by others in the comments, this actually is a closer match to a couple Farscape episodes:

Beware of Dog, in which the crew engages an alien dog-like tracker called a Vorc to hunt down a dangerous parasite.

Coup by Clam, in which the crew are all poisoned/infected by parasites in mollusks, which is a well-known danger by the locals on the planet, but used to get the crew to do the dirty work of the local planetary resistance movement under threat of legal trouble (being diagnosed with "space madness" by a corrupt doctor).


Like with the Star Trek episodes above, there are other miscellaneous plot point matches in other Farscape episodes (parasites: "A Bug's Life", "Liars, Guns and Money part 3"), legal troubles with local planetary authorities followed by fleeing the system (too many to recite), and so forth.
Proving a negative is generally really hard to do (citation needed); as such, all I can do is direct you to Wikipedia's List of Farscape episodes and the always-excellent Ex Astris Scientia's voluminous list of Star Trek episodes so you can verify for yourself that none of the episodes of these series exactly match what you have recounted.
